# Irreducible polynomial clarification

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am not sure if the polynomial:
$f(x) = x^3 +1 \in \mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z$
has roots. I think that it has a root $x = 2$ because $2^3 + 1 \equiv 0(\mod3)$
Is this true? because my professor claimed today that is has no roots, maybe he was confused with something else or I am the one who is wrong...

Comment: yes 2 is a root

Comment: It surely has a root, as $x^3 + 1 \equiv (x + 1)^3 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: In the field $K=\Bbb F_3$ is is an equation, perhaps that's easier to see: $2^3+1=9=0$. Your professor was talking about $x^4+1$, perhaps.

Comment: It even has a root in $\mathbb Z$.  I think there was just a misunderstanding or careless error.

Comment: @lulu I think he wanted $f$ to be $f(x) = x^4 +1$ which indeed, does not have roots.

Comment: Sure.  Some simple error like that is always possible.